# How to see Guzzle HTTP Client request/response in Symfony's profiler

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 5.2 and in the debug toolbar there's an HTTP Client section

My understanding is that it's primary made for the symfony's own http client https://symfony.com/components/HttpClient because it has the [HTTPClientDataCollector](https://github.com/symfony/http-client/blob/ef85ca5fa7a4f9c57592fab49faeccdf22b13136/DataCollector/HttpClientDataCollector.php)

I would like to know it's possible to make Guzzle also implement this kind of data collector ? if so how to do it ? having the http request and response in the profiler would help debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You could install a [eightpoints/guzzle-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/eightpoints/guzzle-bundle)